# Show that the metrix space $( \mathcal{C}(\Omega ), d)$ is not normable

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

$\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ . Given any function $f \in \mathcal{C}(\Omega)$ and any compact
subset $K$ of $\Omega,$ let
$$|f|_{K} :=\sup _{x \in K}|f(x)| .$$
Suppose that $K_i$ is a sequence of compact subset of $\Omega$ such that $$
K_{i} \subset \operatorname{int} K_{i+1} \text { for all } i \geq 1 \text { and } \Omega=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} K_{i}$$
Let $\alpha_i$ be a sequence of positive numbers whose sum is finite.For $f,g \in \mathcal{C}(\Omega )$ define $$
d(f, g) :=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \alpha_{i} \frac{|f-g|_{K_{i}}}{1+|f-g|_{K_{i}}}
$$
The problem asks me to show that $d$ defines a distance, but the corresponding metric space is not normable, i.e. we cannot find a norm which induces the same topology.

I have shown that $d$ is a distance and the metric space is complete.

My trouble is that I do not know what method can be used to show that a metric space is not normable. I have also searched on this site and find some discussions that use results on Rudin, which I do not know.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It is shown in Rudin's Functional Analysis that a space is normable iff there is a bounded convex neighborhood of $0$. It is also shown in it that a subset of $E$ this space is bounded iff $sup_{f \in E} \sup_{x \in K_n} |f(x)| <\infty $ for each $n$. Now take any ball $B(0,\epsilon)$ show that it cannot be bounded. (You can find a continuous function which is 'small' on any  $K_n$ but 'large' on $K_{n+1}$.

Comment: Could you please tell me in which section can I find these results?

Comment: I have an Eastern edition of the book. In it the theorems are  Theorem 1.37 b) and Theorem 1.39. @j200932

Comment: Okey I have seen them, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another argument : assume the space is normable by $\|\cdot\|$. Then, $\|\cdot\|_K \leq C_K\|\cdot\|$, for some constant $C_K$ for any compact $K \subset \Omega$.

Define now a sequence of open balls $B_n=B(x_n,\epsilon_n)$ such that $B_n$ does not meet $K_{n-1}$ but $B_n$ is in the interior of $K_n$.

There exists $h \in \mathscr{C}(\Omega)$ such that its support is contained in the union of the $B_n$, and $h(x_n) = n(1+C_{K_n}^2)$.

Then for all $n$, $\|h\| \geq n\frac{1+C_{K_n}^2}{C_{K_n}}$, a contradiction.

Comment: Excuse me, but I can't see why the statement in your first paragraph is true?

Comment: Because $Id : (\mathscr{C}(\Omega),\|\cdot\|) \rightarrow (\mathscr{C}(\Omega),\|\cdot\|_K+\|\cdot\|)$ is continuous, because this statement is equivalent to: if $d(f_n,g) \rightarrow 0$, then $\|f_n-g\|_K \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Then how does continuity imply your inequality $\| \cdot \|_K \leq C \| \cdot \|$?

Comment: Because a linear continuous mapping between normed spaces is Lipschitz.